# How to change font size of specific parts of code in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In notepad++ we are able to change visible-to-user parts of the code. Is there any way to do the same in VS Code?

Like this:

```
<p>**88888888**</p>
```

tag font size = 9

88888888 font size = 15

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as of VS Code 1.24. Two related issues:

- [support font-size in DecorationRenderOption](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9078) - Would allow extension to change font size
- [Support fontName in textMateRules](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36512) — Would allow themes to change font sizes. The `fontSize` theme property is currently not supported

Answer (score 0):

VS Code's *extension API* supports this since version 1.86 courtesy of PR [Support dynamic line heights using decorations #194609](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/194609) for issue [#147067](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147067). The [`DecorationOptions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationOptions) type (which is the type of one of the parameters for [`TextEditor.setDecorations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor)) has a `lineHeight` property that you can use to increase the line height / font size for text covered by that decoration. Kinks are still being ironed out, and at the time of this writing, it only supports increasing size and not decreasing.